# gmail rejecting (postfix) .forwarded messages

Tags: postfix, gmail

For 15 years I've been forwarding email from my lab's mail server to gmail using a .forward file that has nothing but a single line containing my gmail address, and it has worked fine until recently.  Suddenly gmail is (sometimes) rejecting mail people send me because it fails an SPF check.

I checked the mail headers and something really strange seems to be happening.  Google is treating my lab's server as if it's trying to send email from the sender's domain.  For example, here is part of a header that shows up when I send an email from my yahoo account to my lab's account:

spf=neutral (google.com: <myhostip> is neither permitted nor denied by domain of pat_morin@yahoo.com

(Here, <myhostip> is the IPv4 address of my server that I don't want to post.)

To me this suggests that gmail thinks <myhostip> is trying to pretend to be sending email from a yahoo.com address, which it's not.  It's just forwarding it, which is clear from the headers.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?